# Laravel migration default value for integer not working

Tags: laravel

I'am using laravel version 6 and database postgresql.
So i try to add column `max_quantity` to existing table `products` with default value set to `2147483647`

```
Schema::table('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->integer('max_quantity')->default(2147483647);
});
```

**Controller**:

```
public function store(CreateProduct $request)
{
   $validated = $request->validated();
   Product::create($validated);
}
```

Here max_quantity look like in postgres

[image]

when I try to create product the errors says

> SQLSTATE[23502]: Not null violation: 7 ERROR:  null value in column
> "max_quantity" violates not-null constraint

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Look like you're trying insert a null value to that field, can you show us your creating product code?

Comment: @catcon yes i didn't notice that :). i just remove `max_quantity` if it set to null.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you'r getting erorr

> SQLSTATE[23502]: Not null violation: 7 ERROR: null value in column
> "max_quantity" violates not-null constraint

because when you create the product you included the `max_quantity` with value `null`
to solve your problem just dont include `max_quantity` if the value is `null`

for example:

```
if ($request->max_quantity == null) {
   unset($request->max_quantity);
}

Product::create($request->only([...]))
```

this way when product created `max_quantity` is set to `2147483647`